# How to use MessageDialog.open() with QUESTION_WITH_CANCEL?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm wondering how to use the new *QUESTION_WITH_CANCEL* dialog kind when opened with `MessageDialog.open(int kind, Shell parent, String title, String message,int style)`.

Since the open method is returning *boolean* and now we have 3 possible state from **Yes**, **No**, or **Cancel**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use the static method `MessageDialog.open(bunch of parameters)`, you'll have to create the Dialog and call the non-static `open()`  yourself to check its return value.

```
    MessageDialog dg = new MessageDialog(
            window.getShell(),
            "My title",
            null,
            "My question",
            MessageDialog.QUESTION_WITH_CANCEL, 
            new String[]{
                IDialogConstants.YES_LABEL, 
                IDialogConstants.NO_LABEL, 
                IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL},
            0
            );
    switch(dg.open()) {
    case 0: 
        //yes
        System.out.println("yes");
        break;
    case 1:
        //no
        System.out.println("no");
        break;
    case 2:
        //cancel
        System.out.println("cancel");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The buttons are in a weird order (Eclipse 3.5.2): No Cancel Yes instead of Yes No Cancel. How do I make them in the "right" order?

Comment: I don't know how to solve the weird order, but I think the reason for it is explained by part of the javadoc for `MessageDialog`: "This class does not use button IDs from IDialogConstants. Instead, the ID is the index of the button in the supplied array."

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/MessageDialog.html), I believe **No** and **Cancel** have the same effect: **false**

```
Returns:
    true if the user presses the OK or Yes button, false otherwise
```

Comment: That much I know, but that is not the question I asked. I do have a need to use the QUESTION_WITH_CANCEL dialog. If I only need standard yes/no, I would have use the standard confirm dialog.